# google search appliance blacklist suggestion

Tags: search-engine, google-search, google-search-appliance

I need to block one suggestion from Google search appliance(GSA), and I have added that in the blacklist and also reset the suggestions so that it will regenerate the query suggestions and will not include that bad word.

The term I am searching is "banding the chicks", and *Did you mean...* comes up with the suggestion "banging the chicks". So I added "banging" to the blacklist suggestion, reset the suggestions and waited till 24 hours, but it didn't work.

Is there any particular way I need to add "banging" to the blacklist?

Any thoughts or help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The blacklist feature is not used for spelling-suggestions, but it's for AutoSuggest-functionality. You can blacklist words or patterns from AutoSuggest, but not for spelling suggestions.

However, with a small frontend tweak you can accomplish the same. Please follow [these](https://support.google.com/gsa/answer/6333977?hl=en) steps!